# How does livingsocial.com automatically have user's logged in with their Facebook account?

Tags: facebook, authentication

Try visiting livingsocial.com and you'll notice that if you're logged into Facebook, you'll automatically be logged in to livingsocial.com. How do they this automatically without having the user click a Login button?

Answer (score 1):

They use 'Facebook Connect'.

Check it out: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web